# Email events in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, email, sinatra, eventmachine

I am working on a `Sinatra` web app that  needs to save any email that it receives in a db (or do something else as soon as a mail is received). What is the best tool for this job? I was looking at `eventmachine` and it seems a bit complex. I was considering the `mail` gem but it doesn't trigger events when mail is recieved. One final query: To test such an app, do I need it to host it online? If not, then how to do I send emails to the app and test?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Sinatra is a web server. Email doesn't come in from HTTP requests, so you need a mail server to receive the emails and assuming you still want to handle them in your Sinatra app, fire a request at your app.

check out http://steve.dynedge.co.uk/2010/09/07/incoming-email-in-rails-3-choosing-the-right-approach/ for a few options (it's thinking rails, but you should be able to translate)